# Qt C++ Q_OBJECT error undefined reference to vtable

Tags: qt

I am constantly running into problems while using the Q_OBJECT macro: (I use QT Creator 2.8.1 / Qt 4.8.4) I asked before but it seems to be leading to even more trouble. Can anybody help me? I am totally lost .

I have a huge C++ program with about 50+ classes to adapt to new needs. 
Now I created a new (very simple) parent-class and 3 child classes in a new directory within the src-directory. To do so I used the template  *Qt->Qt Designer Form Class.*( I did that because this automatically implements Q_OBJECT  even though  I do not need a *.ui-file. I then removed all concerning ui-Fileand the ui-file itself))

When I run my program I always get lots of „ u*ndefined reference to vtable for“* ..-errors. When I remove all Q_OBJECT my program runs OK. But then I am not able to use signal-slots which I would need later on.

I looked it up in the internet and found out it has something to do with the .pro-file/.o-Files in my build-directory. I (several times)  tried to delete all .o-Files including the .pro.user and compile again. Sometimes I still got the error, sometimes not.

This is my code ( the 3 child classes are the same at the moment):

```
geometry.h:

    #ifndef GEOMETRY_H
    #define GEOMETRY_H
    #include <QMetaType>        
    #include <QWidget>
    #include <QObject>   
    #include <QDebug>        

    class Geometry
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    protected:

    public:
        Geometry();
        virtual ~Geometry(void) {}

        virtual void write_LNE(); 

    //Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Geometry);
    #endif // GEOMETRY_H
```

-

```
geometry.cpp:

#include "geometry.h"

    Geometry::Geometry()
    { qDebug() << "Constructor:  hier ist Geometry";        }


    void Geometry::Haupt()
    {  qDebug() << " Das hier ist die Haupt von Geometry ....." ; }      
    void Geometry::write_LNE(){}
```

-

```
 Geo_1PF.h:

    #ifndef GEO_1PF_H
    #define GEO_1PF_H
    #include "geometry.h"

    class Geo_1PF : public Geometry
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        Geo_1PF();
        ~Geo_1PF() {}

        virtual void write_LNE();        
    };

    //Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Geo_1PF);
    #endif // GEO_1PF_H
```

- Geo_1PF.cpp:

  ```
   #include "Geo_1PF.h"

   Geo_1PF::Geo_1PF()
  {
  }
  ```

I found the advice to do qmake manually. I never used qmake manually.

- **How and from which directory do I do this ? Exactly what do I write qmake …….?**
- **Is it correct to use the template  Qt->Qt Designer Form Class to create these classes?**
- **Do I have to create the classes in another directory?**
- **Are there any additional entries I have to make in the +.pro-File**
- **and where in the file do they have tob be put?**
- **Do I have to change anything in my makefile? And if so what?**

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the QOBJECT macro in your class you need to extend QObject.

```
class MyObject: public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
MyObject (QObject *_parent);

.....

};
```

Comment: I still get the undefined reference to vtable-Error

Comment: Sometimes the moc files aren't regenerated so you have to Build->Clean all and Build->Run qmake which usually fixes those issues.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Qt Creator:
Everytime you create a class using Q_OBJECT,

- Build → Run qmake
- Build → Rebuild All

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it for me as well.